# How to access 64-bit HKLM\Software Registry with a 32-bit C#.NET Application

Tags: c#, registry, 64-bit

So I needed to read all the applications installed on the PC, but the problem is that part of them are in a 64-Bit Registry Value, thus I couldn't read it with a 32-Bit application.

So I need to set it to read a 64-Bit Value, and by doing so I'll be able to read with my 32-Bit application a 64-Bit Registry Value. I'll show here my case for the example.

Comment: When self-answering (which is perfectly valid), you should make the question *read as a question*. "The solution is quite simple" isn't a sentence you'd expect to find at the start of a question.

Comment: Noted, I'll edit it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read all 32-Bit applications in the Registry:

```
string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
        {
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var displayName = sk.GetValue("DisplayName");
                        var size = sk.GetValue("EstimatedSize");

                        ListViewItem item;
                        if (displayName != null)
                        {
                            if (size != null)
                                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { displayName.ToString(), size.ToString(), rk.OpenSubKey(skName).ToString() });
                            else
                                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { displayName.ToString(), null, rk.OpenSubKey(skName).ToString() });
                            listInstalled.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is how I read all 64-Bit applications in the Registry:

```
string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
RegistryKey regkey64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey rk64 = regkey64.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey);
foreach (string skName in rk64.GetSubKeyNames())
{
        using (RegistryKey sk = rk64.OpenSubKey(skName))
        {
                try
                {
                    var displayName = sk.GetValue("DisplayName");
                    var size = sk.GetValue("EstimatedSize");

                    ListViewItem item;
                    if (displayName != null)
                    {
                        if (size != null)
                            item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { displayName.ToString(), size.ToString(), rk64.OpenSubKey(skName).ToString() });
                        else
                            item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { displayName.ToString(), null, rk64.OpenSubKey(skName).ToString() });
                        listInstalled.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
        }
}
```

In case you haven't noticed the differences so here they are in **BOLD** this time:

32-Bit: ***RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey)***

64-Bit: ***RegistryKey regkey64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey rk64 = regkey64.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey);***

Although it's documented in Microsoft's site, I decided to write it here cause that made me a LOT of trouble. And the reason you couldn't read it is simply because it's a 64-Bit value (which cannot be regularly accessed by a 32-bit application - to confirm that yourself, in the name of science; run it first only with the 32-bit code, then press Alt-Enter>Build>uncheck "Prefer 32-bit". Now run it again and you'll see it shows all the 64-bit applications).

I hope this would be useful. You can look at the "trick" here and apply it on your code. gl hf :)